# How to speed up/slow down a video frame by frame

Tags: video-processing

I am working with video files, converting it to frames and I was wondering how could I speed up or slow down the total time of a video, by adding/removing some frames. I want to simulate time-stretch of a video, and I need to manipulate that operation frame by frame.
I am using AS3 for this, but any help in other languages will be enough for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To speed up or slow down, you typically do not add or remove frames. You just adjust the delay time between frame displays. So, if you video was 10FPS FRAMETIME = (1.0 / 10) then to play it at 20 FPS as fast you set FRAMETIME = (1.0 / 20). In the extreme case where the system cannot keep up with a fast frame display interval, your code should skip ahead to catch up to the "system time".

Answer (score 1):

use ffmpeg a cmd tool .
To slow down your video, you have to use a multiplier greater than 1:

ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" output.mkv
use 2.0 or 3.0

[reference](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)